Change ConnectionFactory settings when using RabbitBus
We got this vulnerability "disable cleartext authentication mechanisms in the amqp configuration" and I am trying to remove that following  rabbitMQ tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ssl
We are using RabbitBus with amqp URL to connect  and now in the rabbitMq documentation I found some changes from client side

How to change connectionfactory settings via RabbitBus?
When I searched for RabbitBus I am not finding any examples to change when using RabbitBus.
In the source file of RabbitBus https://github.com/derekgreer/rabbitBus/blob/master/src/RabbitBus/Bus.cs They are enabling it using amqpURL only
Thanks,
Nagasree.
